# std::find conditional statement not working as expected

Tags: c++, vector, struct, std

So I'm trying to write a loop with a conditional statement that compares the member of a `struct`, and if the member value matches the requirement outputs some data.

The structs are stored in a vector that an encapsulating for loop iterates through using `const_iterator usersInItr`. The struct contains a string for the username, and a string vector for the groups of type `std::vector<std::string> groups`.

This is the specific part of the code being troublesome:

```
//Look for member group to proceed with output
if(*std::find(usersInItr->groups.begin(),usersInItr->groups.end(),"member")=="member")
{    
    ConfigFile << usersInItr->username << std::endl;
}
else
{
    std::cout << "Nope" << std::endl;
}
```

The idea being that the `std::find` statement searches through the group string vector of each user structure to check if it contains the string "member". From what I understand from the documentation, `std::find` will return an iterator which points at the index that contains the member, or if not found just the last item in the container. So I dereference the iterator from the `std::find` function and check to see if it matches.

However it does not work. When the `groups` vector does not contain a "member" entry the TRUE branch still runs. I tried outputting the statement on its own:

```
std::cout << *std::find(usersInItr->groups.begin(),usersInItr->groups.end(),"member") << std::endl;
```

It always outputs "member", even when the groups string vector doesn't contain the term...so I'm not sure what's going on here. From my understanding of the function this should work.

Thanks!

Comment: Please post [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). What is the type of `usersInItr->groups`? By the way, [`std::find`](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/find.html) will return the **"item" just past of the last item**, not the last item, so do not dereference the returned iterator without checking!

Comment: It is a `std::vector<std::string> groups` and I have added that into into the original question.

If I understand that correctly it would point to an invalid location...how does that work? Wouldn't the item just past the last index be some random data?

Comment: `std::find` will return `end()` if the item isn't found, which isn't dereferencable - your program will invoke undefined behaviour (and possibly crash) if the item isn't found. `end()` is not the last item in the container, it's one-past the last item.

Comment: Ok, so end() is a different than the actual last index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The iterator returned from `std::find` will point **"item" just past of the last item**, not the last item, so do not dereference it without checking.

To see if an item was found, you should write like this:

```
if(std::find(usersInItr->groups.begin(),usersInItr->groups.end(),"member") != usersInItr->groups.end())
{    
    ConfigFile << usersInItr->username << std::endl;
}
else
{
    std::cout << "Nope" << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By the way which operations on groups vector do you do more often? I suspect that testing that user is member of the some group. I just curious that in yours case the set of string is better solution. In my opinion testing existence of element in set is more comfortable than other containers and its complexity is better than find operation on vector. Of course for quick searching you must pay by slower insertion.

```cpp
std::set<std::string> s;
s.insert( "some group" );
s.insert( "member" );
s.insert( "another group" );

if( s.count( "member" ) > 0 )
  std::cout << "Yes";
else
  std::cout << "No";
```

For more details please refer http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/